# Find the element before and after a specific element with pure javascript

Tags: javascript

Having a list with links like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">First tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Second tab</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Active tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fourth tab</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fifth tab</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can be found element before and after the active tab? (In this case, the second and fourth tab).

---

I am looking for solution in **pure JavaScript** only, as jQuery solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929670/find-the-element-before-and-after-a-specific-element).

**Note:** `nextElementSibling` and `previousElementSibling` are not supported by IE8 and FF3, so please post solutions that would be supported by those browsers as well. Thank you.

Comment: perhaps something like this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574904/get-next-previous-element-using-javascript

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Assuming your `<ul>` element is called `element`:

```
var active, prev, next;
active = prev = next = element.querySelector('.active');

do prev = prev.previousSibling; while(prev && prev.nodeType !== 1);
do next = next.nextSibling;     while(next && next.nodeType !== 1);
```

This will work in Internet Explorer 8.

If you're only worried about modern browsers:

```
var active = element.querySelector('.active');
var prev = active.previousElementSibling;
var next = active.nextElementSibling;
```

Answer (score 23):

Pretty easily, given an up-to-date browser:

```js
// here we first retrieve the currently-active element, via
// document.getElementsByClassName(), using bracket-notation
// to access a specific element-node from the HTMLCollection;
// the zeroth element is the first element in the array-like
// collection:
const activeTab = document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0],
  // from that element-node we find the previous sibling element:
  activePrevSibling = activeTab.previousElementSibling,
  // and also the next sibling element:
  activeNextSibling = activeTab.nextElementSibling;

// we then set the background-color of these elements:
activeTab.style.backgroundColor = '#0f0';
activePrevSibling.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
activeNextSibling.style.backgroundColor = '#00f';
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5em;
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
  width: clamp(20em, 80vw, 600px);
}

li {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  font-size: 2em;
  place-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  background-color: #fffa;
  border-radius: 1em;
  color: #000;
  padding-block: 0.25em;
  padding-inline: 0.5em;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: transparent;
  text-underline-offset: 0.01em;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

a:focus-visible {
  background-color: #fffc;
  outline-color: currentColor;
  outline-offset: 0.1em;
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-width: 0.2em;
  scale: 1.2;
}

a:active,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration-color: currentColor;
  text-underline-offset: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">First tab</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Second tab</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Active tab</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Fourth tab</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Fifth tab</a></li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FTJHj/64/) (with horrible, *horrible* colours...).

---

The above edited, based on the comment left by Esailija:

> `document.querySelector(".active")` is more supported and concise:

```js
// exactly as above, with the exception we're now retrieving the first,
// and only, element from the document that matches the supplied CSS
// selector; bear in mind that this method will return null if no
// matching element is found; so sanity-checks should be used in
// production code:
const activeTab = document.querySelector(".active"),
  activePrevSibling = activeTab.previousElementSibling,
  activeNextSibling = activeTab.nextElementSibling;

activeTab.style.backgroundColor = '#0f0';
activePrevSibling.style.backgroundColor = '#f00';
activeNextSibling.style.backgroundColor = '#00f';
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5em;
  margin-block: 1em;
  margin-inline: auto;
  width: clamp(20em, 80vw, 600px);
}

li {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 1em;
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  font-size: 2em;
  place-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  background-color: #fffa;
  border-radius: 1em;
  color: #000;
  padding-block: 0.25em;
  padding-inline: 0.5em;
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-decoration-color: transparent;
  text-underline-offset: 0.01em;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

a:focus-visible {
  background-color: #fffc;
  outline-color: currentColor;
  outline-offset: 0.1em;
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-width: 0.2em;
  scale: 1.2;
}

a:active,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration-color: currentColor;
  text-underline-offset: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">First tab</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Second tab</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="#">Active tab</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Fourth tab</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Fifth tab</a></li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FTJHj/).

References:

- [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.nextElementSibling).
- [`previousElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Element.previousElementSibling).

Comment: `document.querySelector(".active")` is more supported and concise ;P

Comment: Really? I (*clearly*, I suppose) never knew that; thanks (and editing-in!)

Comment: @Esailija: Well, any browser that supports `*ElementSibling` also supports `getElementsByClassName`... but it is definitely more concise. I wonder how it performs in comparison?

Comment: @minitech: I feel a JS Perf coming on..!

Comment: @minitech IIRC in a fair test (that takes into account the nature of live nodelists vs static ones), it's only 2x slower. In an [unfair test](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/09/28/why-is-getelementsbytagname-faster-that-queryselectorall/), it's 99x slower.

Comment: `nextElementSibling` is not supported by IE8, FF3

Comment: http://jsperf.com/getting-elements-by-class-name; `getElementsByClassName` wins by a landslide! (At least on my browser.)

Comment: @minitech exactly what I was referring to by an unfair test ;d

Comment: @Esailija: It's not unfair, because I fetch an element... right?

Comment: @Ωmega: David was pointing this out explicitly: *"[...] given an up-to-date browser"*.

Comment: @FelixKling - let's update browser to all users worldwide - easy task, right? :-/

Comment: Seriously, IE8 I can understand, but FF3? Does that have a large enough market share to worry about? Typically users of Firefox are those that are happy to install a new browser, so I can't imagine they'd leave Firefox to go so out-of-date.

Comment: @minitech It's just using [cache](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/dom/DynamicNodeList.cpp#L85).  But the initial search of the element from dom was just as slow as it was with the querySelector, minus the time to parse a css selector. To test properly, you'd have to flush the cache everytime and subtract the time it takes to flush the cache (modify the dom so that the cached nodelist is invalid). Also, if you think about it, why would it magically fetch nodes from dom hundreds of times faster?